# Key-Value data on GAE Datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I read the documentation of GAE Datastore, but it's a bit.. too hard for me to understand. What I need is just a simple key-value option. Any way to do this? I'd prefer doing this in couple lines of code, because it's simpel as pie. Idk why there isn't an API for doing this.

Comment: Errm, there is an API. In fact several, JDO, JPA, low-level.

Comment: See objectify (http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/)

Comment: Didn't knew it support JPA also, I really prefer it over JDO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE's datastore is already an Key-Value storage, where value is any Map. This map can have one or more elements.